# Api Platform with Swift Mailer

Tags: api, email, symfony4, swiftmailer, api-platform.com

I would know if [API Platform](https://api-platform.com/docs/distribution/) is reliable to [Swift Mailer](https://symfony.com/doc/current/email.html). In fact, I woul use Swift Mailer to send a email when a new task has add. It works good when I use my controller, but not working with Postman or Swagger UI.

```
//mail sending
       $message = (new \Swift_Message('New task has done !'))
           ->setContentType('text/html')
           ->setFrom("fromAdresse@sample.fr")
           ->setTo('sample@email.com')
           ->setBody(
               $this->renderView('email/new.html.twig',
                    ['work' => $work]));
        $mailer->send($message);
```

I would use the same thing when users pass by the API UI, it's possible to handle the request ? Because controller and API hasn't the same route.

> API : /api/works (POST) to add an element
>
> Controller : work/new (POST) to add an element too

How I can use Swift Mailer on the API platform Request ? Or How I can handle the request with custom controller ?

Thx for advice and answers, I'm beginer with both.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best way is using an Entity listener (see https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html) - you can detect create/update/delete actions there and do other actions like send e-mails. It is also better to have message logic at one place for all controller/api/other requests :-)

Just be careful to select the right Doctrine event. And read details about modifying entities inside these listeners (i.e. to store "email sent" flag or any other values to other entities. It is not straightforward :-) ).